# How do I go back 'twice' (or more) with next/router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I decided to go with router.back() as an onClick callback instead of the conventional href for my breadcrumbs because I wanted the query to persist e.g.:

1. list of chargers `/chargers?p=5&q=solent&type=2`
2. charger `/chargers/162`

- if i give an href of /chargers, all the search filters and queries made by the user would disappear
- if I do router.back(), it would keep all this.

The problem comes in when pages are nested i.e.:
`/chargers/162/images`. If a user wants to go back to /chargers, I would have to do something like this,

```
     const goBack = (goToPageIndex: number) => {
        const currentPageIndex = breadcrumbs.length
        const amountOfTimesToGoBack = currentPageIndex - goToPageIndex
    
        for (let i = 1; i < amountOfTimesToGoBack; i += 1) {
          router.back()
        }
      }
```

which I don't like very much and also throws warning like
`Error: Abort fetching component for route /chargers/162` despite it working anyway (not sure how that would hold up in prod)

What would be the best way to go about this? Thank you

Comment: Can you store the filters of the user in localstorage and just link to `/chargers` . On page load you check if there are filters stored in localstorage and apply them again.

Comment: Or maybe even better: If you know the current filters also on server side, you can just use the actual link with all query params already applied to it (built dynamically on BE side)  (sorry for the double comment, I can't edit it anymore)

Comment: @cloned I try not to use web storage too much since it can be difficult to maintain but I will give that a go ! Thanks

Comment: True, you have to define when to clear the sotrage and everything. Depending on your users, maybe you can add a text like "Your previous filters were re-applied, to clear them click here" or something (or go the other way round: Show a message with "if you want to re-apply your last filters, click here" ... This totally depends on your users and what would work best for them.